# Making an external file for my javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this questions been asked multiple times, but I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong when I am referencing my javascript code.   It works just fine when I put the code in the body.  However, when I make the javascript code separate on its own it does not work.  Any help would be very much apperciated.  Thank you

```js
(function( $ ) {

    //Function to animate slider captions 
 function doAnimations( elems ) {
  //Cache the animationend event in a variable
  var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';
  
  elems.each(function () {
   var $this = $(this),
    $animationType = $this.data('animation');
   $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
    $this.removeClass($animationType);
   });
  });
 }
 
 //Variables on page load 
 var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
  $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
  
 //Initialize carousel 
 $myCarousel.carousel();
 
 //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
 doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);
 
 //Pause carousel  
 $myCarousel.carousel('pause');
 
 
 //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
 $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
  doAnimations($animatingElems);
 });  
    $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
        interval:3000,
        pause: "false"
    });
 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav {
  border-width: 1px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #0b0b0b, #494848);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 77px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Allerta', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 100 line-height: 1.7857;
  letter-spacing: .075em;
  float: right !important;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}



/*
Bootstrap Image Carousel Slider with Animate.css
Code snippet by Hashif (http://hashif.com) for Bootsnipp.com
Image credits: unsplash.com
*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700);

body {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
}





/********************************/
/*          Main CSS     */
/********************************/


#first-slider .main-container {
  padding: 0;
}


#first-slider .slide1 h3, #first-slider .slide2 h3, #first-slider .slide3 h3, #first-slider .slide4 h3{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight:700;
}

#first-slider .slide1 h4,#first-slider .slide2 h4,#first-slider .slide3 h4,#first-slider .slide4 h4{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight:700;
}
#first-slider .slide1 .text-left ,#first-slider .slide3 .text-left{
    padding-left: 40px;
}


#first-slider .carousel-indicators {
  bottom: 0;
}
#first-slider .carousel-control.right,
#first-slider .carousel-control.left {
  background-image: none;
}
#first-slider .carousel .item {
  min-height: 425px; 
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

.carousel-inner .item .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}


#first-slider h3{
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
#first-slider h4 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
#first-slider h2 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}


#first-slider .carousel-control {
    width: 6%;
        text-shadow: none;
}


#first-slider h1 {
  text-align: center;  
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#first-slider .p {
  padding-top: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

#first-slider .p a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#first-slider .carousel-indicators li {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  border:none;
}
#first-slider .carousel-indicators .active{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
  border:none;
}


.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-control .fa-angle-right, .carousel-control .fa-angle-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}
.carousel-control .fa-angle-left{
    left: 50%;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
    -moz-border-radius: 23px;
    border-radius: 53px;
}
.carousel-control .fa-angle-right{
    right: 50%;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
    -moz-border-radius: 23px;
    border-radius: 53px;
}
.carousel-control {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}


/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
#first-slider .slide1 {
    background-image: url(http://s20.postimg.org/h50tgcuz1/image.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#first-slider .slide2 {
  background-image: url(http://s20.postimg.org/uxf8bzlql/image.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#first-slider .slide3 {
  background-image: url(http://s20.postimg.org/el56m97f1/image.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#first-slider .slide4 {
  background-image: url(http://s20.postimg.org/66pjy66dp/image.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}




/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
      
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
      
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title> Hayat Express</title>


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/1slider.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/animate.css/3.5.1/animate.min.css">




<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body>

  <ul class="nav">

    <img src="logos/navbar-logo.png">

    <li><a class="hover" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#Drivers">Drivers</a></li>
  </ul>


<div id="first-slider">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <!-- Item 1 -->
            <div class="item active slide1">
                <div class="row"><div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                        <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/pfmmo6qj1/window_domain.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                        <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">Add images, or even your logo!</h3>
                        <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Easily use stunning effects</h4>             
                     </div>
                </div></div>
             </div> 
            <!-- Item 2 -->
            <div class="item slide2">
                <div class="row"><div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                        <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown"> 50 animation options A beautiful</h3>
                        <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Create beautiful slideshows </h4>
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                        <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/sp11uneml/rack_server_unlock.png">
                    </div>
                </div></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item 3 -->
            <div class="item slide3">
                <div class="row"><div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                        <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">Simple Bootstrap Carousel</h3>
                        <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Bootstrap Image Carousel Slider with Animate.css</h4>
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                        <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/eq8xvxeq5/globe_network.png">
                    </div>     
                </div></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item 4 -->
            <div class="item slide4">
                <div class="row"><div class="container">
                    <div class="col-md-7 text-left">
                        <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInDown">We are creative</h3>
                        <h4 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">Get start your next awesome project</h4>
                     </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 text-right">
                        <img style="max-width: 200px;"  data-animation="animated zoomInLeft" src="http://s20.postimg.org/9vf8xngel/internet_speed.png">
                    </div>  
                </div></div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Item 4 -->
    
        </div>
        <!-- End Wrapper for slides-->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>


<footer>
    
</footer>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pretty simple, you include it before you include jQuery.  I am sure the error in your console says something to that effect

Comment: Wait you have TWO versions of jQuery.... why..... The slim version is going to kill the slider code most likely....

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome Dev Tools and key in evaluate $ to see if jQuery is properly linked. If you receive jQuery information back, they you're in the clear.

You may also want to add your scripts like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/1slider.js"></script>
```

To denote as javascript. If that doesn't work, then verify the path to your JS file.

Answer (score 0):

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.

try loading jquery right before the `</body>`

[Bootstrap How to load JS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)